# runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode' (solution.cpp)

Tags: linked-list

i am practicing some problem on linked list and i got the error inside the while loop. Inside the while loop the the temp1 variable is getting the error . why this error is coming and how to solve it ?
code:-

```
void reorderList(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* mid=midFinder(head);
        reverseList(head,mid);
        mid=midFinder(head);
        ListNode* list1=head;
        while(list1->next!=mid){
            list1=list1->next;
        }
        list1->next=NULL;
        ListNode* first=head;
        ListNode* second=mid;
        while(second){
            ListNode* temp1=first->next;
            ListNode* temp2=second->next;
            
            first->next=second;
            second->next=temp1;

            second=temp2;
            first=temp1;

        }
    }
```

i have divided the original inked list in two part one start from head and another start form mid element. then in the while loop i tried to reorder the list by joining them alternatively.